# How to convert .txt to .csv file in R

Tags: r, csv, txt

I found this code here, and it worked to convert the '.txt' to '.csv' but the file is not broken into columns, pretty sure there's an easy fix or line to add here, but I'm not finding it. Still new to r and working through, so any help or direction is appreciated.

EDIT:  The file contains the following, a list of invasive plants:

Header: Noxious Weed List.

'(a) Abrus precatorius – rosary pea '

'(b) Aeginetia spp. – aeginetia'

'(c) Ageratina adenophora – crofton weed '

'(d) Alectra spp. – alectra '

And so I would like to get all the parts, i.e., genus, species, and common name, in a separate column. and if possible, delete the letters '(a)' and the ' - ' separating hyphen.

```
filelist = list.files(pattern = ".txt")
for (i in 1:length(filelist)) {
  input<-filelist[i]
  output <- paste0(gsub("\\.txt$", "", input), ".csv")
  print(paste("Processing the file:", input))
  data = read.delim(input, header = TRUE)
  write.table(data, file=output, sep=",", col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the contents of the file? A "txt" file isn't very descriptive -- anything could be in there.

Comment: I think you can use regex to parse each line, I'm no regex expert but something like `line %>% str_match("\(.*\)(.*–[^–])(.*)")`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to adjust if you have common names with three or more words, but this is the general idea:

```
path <- "C:\\Your File Path Here\\"
file <- paste0(path, "WeedList.txt")
DT <- read.delim(file, header = FALSE, sep = " ")
DT <- DT[-c(1),-c(1,4,7)]
colnames(DT) <- c("Genus", "Species", "CommonName", "CommonName2")
DT$CommonName <- gsub("'", "", DT$CommonName)
DT$CommonName2 <- gsub("'", "", DT$CommonName2)
DT$CommonName <- paste(DT$CommonName, DT$CommonName2, sep = " ")
DT <- DT[,-c(4)]
write.csv(DT, paste0(path, "WeedList.csv"), row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: This worked! @cgrafe  I will need to tweak a few things and test some more, and then will post my edits soon. Many thanks.